# Is there a grammatically correct replacement for "a whole nother level" that retains the intended meaning and emphasis?

Tags: grammaticality, phrase-requests, idioms

In the sentence "I had had great experiences before, but this one was like *a whole nother level*", I understand the idea, but I'm also aware that saying *a whole nother* is not grammatical. Is there an alternative way of saying the same sentence such that 1) it's grammatically correct and 2) does not lose the original meaning and emphasis?

Comment: "_This was on a whole other level_" is grammatically and idiomatically correct

Comment: Does this answer your question? [word that means: causing a paradigm shift, new era, revolution](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83521/word-that-means-causing-a-paradigm-shift-new-era-revolution) 'But this was a _quantum leap_.'

Comment: A completely different level

Comment: "a whole nother level" is perhaps not appropriate for formal writing, but it is certainly grammatical.

Comment: Why do you think "a whole nother" is not grammatical?

Answer (score 3):

"Another" is ambiguous: "another N" can mean "an additional N" or "an alternative N". So, according to which of those senses you mean, I suggest "a whole other level" and "a whole different level".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "a whole 'nother level," you could say the following: paramount, superior, revolutionary, unparalleled, or incomparable.

Of the words listed above, I think "unparalleled" best conveys the intended meaning of your sentence.

"I had had great experiences before, but this one was *unparalleled*."

If you want, you can qualify unparalleled to be more specific: unparalleled in its _______ .

Answer (score -1):

"Whole 'nother" is often paired with "use ta could".  Those who use these types of colloquialisms often have additional meaning than a more grammatically correct term.  Any word/phrase you can use to get another human to understand you is good, spelling it with correct punctuation can indicate that is the way you intended, if not using the latin (sic).  Dadda beda!

Comment: How is "whole 'nother" paired with "used ta could"? Do you mean people who use the first expression also use the second? I have heard "a whole 'nother" plenty of times and say it myself, but I don't recall having heard "used ta could" and have certainly never said it.